# Want to format UDF Usb Readonly drive to NTFS

Tags: ntfs, format, read-only, file-format, udf

new here. I have a usb of 32gb which I got form a course I enrolled. Now I want to format the usb and use it for my personal use but I cannot format it. Can anyone help or should I just throw it?

Comment: "but I cannot format it." we need to guess what not? it might be hardware wired to be read only.

Comment: Be sure it's not mounted (see `man umount mtab`) and that none of the partitions on the USB key is mounted. Carefully examine the USB key, does it have a sliding switch on it?